# Maclaurin's series for $\log(1+ \tan x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, solution-verification

I tried to find Maclaurin's expansion for $\log (1 + \tan x)$ by algebraic method as below but coefficients of $x^6$ and $x^7$ are not matching what is given in [Mathematica](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maclaurin+Series+for+log%281%2B+tan+x%29).

What did I do wrong? I am not able to spot it.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\tan x &= x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \frac{17}{315}x^7 + \ldots\\
\log (1+x) &= x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^5}{5}- \ldots \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

So,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\log (1+\tan x) &= \tan x - \frac{(\tan x)^2}{2} + \frac{(\tan x)^3}{3} - \frac{(\tan x)^4}{4} + \frac{(\tan x)^5}{5}- \ldots \\
\end{split}
(\#eq:4ii)
\end{equation*}

Lets find values of numerators in the fractions,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(\tan x)^2 &= \left(x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \frac{17}{315}x^7 + \ldots\right)^2 \\
&= x^2 + 2x\left(\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \frac{17}{315}x^7 + \ldots\right) + \left(\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \frac{17}{315}x^7 + \ldots \right)^2 \\
&= x^2 + \frac{2x^4}{3} + \frac{4x^6}{15} + \ldots + \frac{x^6}{9} + \ldots\\
&= x^2 + \frac{2x^4}{3} + \frac{17x^6}{45} + \ldots\\
(\tan x)^3 &= \left(x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \frac{17}{315}x^7 + \ldots \right)^3 \\
&= x^3 + 3x^2 \left(\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \ldots\right) + 3x\left(\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \ldots\right)^2 + \\
& \left(\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \ldots\right)^3\\
&= x^3 + \frac{3x^5}{3} + \frac{6x^7}{15}+ \ldots + \frac{3x^7}{9} + \frac{12x^9}{45} + \ldots + \frac{x^9}{27} + \ldots \\
&= x^3 + \frac{3x^5}{3} + \frac{11x^7}{15}+ \ldots \\
(\tan x)^4 &= \left(x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \frac{17}{315}x^7 + \ldots\right)^4 \\
&= x^4 + 4x^3\left(\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \ldots\right) + \ldots\\
&= x^4 + \frac{4x^6}{3} + \ldots\\
(\tan x)^5 &= \left(x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \frac{17}{315}x^7 + \ldots\right)^5 \\
&= x^5 + 5x^4\left(\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \ldots\right) + \ldots\\
&= x^5 + \frac{5x^7}{3} +  \ldots
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Lets put these values in equation @ref(eq:4ii),

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\log (1+\tan x) &= \tan x - \frac{(\tan x)^2}{2} + \frac{(\tan x)^3}{3} - \frac{(\tan x)^4}{4} + \frac{(\tan x)^5}{5}- \ldots \\
&= \left(x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \frac{17}{315}x^7 + \ldots\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(x^2 + \frac{2x^4}{3} + \frac{17x^6}{45} + \ldots\right) + \\
& \frac{1}{3}\left(x^3 + \frac{3x^5}{3} + \frac{11x^7}{15}+ \ldots\right) - \frac{1}{4}\left(x^4 + \frac{4x^6}{3} + \ldots\right) + \\
& \frac{1}{5}\left(x^5+ \frac{5x^7}{3} + \ldots\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Now collecting coefficients of $x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6, x^7$,

[image]

Expansion is then,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\log (1+\tan x) &= x -\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{2}{3}x^3 - \frac{7}{12}x^4 + \frac{2}{3}x^5 -\frac{47}{90}x^6 + \frac{199}{315}x^7 - \ldots 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: You should continue on to $(\tan x)^6$ and $(\tan x)^7$ (because these terms look like $(x+ \dots)^6$ and $(x+ \dots)^7$, so they will also contribute to the overall $x^6$ and $x^7$ terms); the issue here is that you have truncated the expansion too early. If you do it with these extra terms and still it doesn't match, then it's just a matter of doing the algebra even more carefully

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you. Just solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you did not account for $\tan^6(x)$ and $\tan^7(x)$, which both contribute to the terms you are looking at.

For a much easier approach, observe that the derivative is given by

\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln(1+\tan(x))&=\frac{\sec^2(x)}{1+\tan(x)}\\&=\frac{1+\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan(x)}\\&=\frac{1+\left(x+\frac13x^3+\frac2{15}x^5\right)^2}{1+x+\frac13x^3+\frac2{15}x^5}+\mathcal O(x^7)\\&=\frac{1+x^2+\frac23x^4+\frac{17}{45}x^6}{1+x+\frac13x^3+\frac2{15}x^5}+\mathcal O(x^7)\\&=1-x+2x^2-\frac73x^3+\frac{10}3x^4-\frac{62}{15}x^5+\frac{244}{45}x^6+\mathcal O(x^7)\end{align}

which can easily be integrated to give the desired result.

Comment: Indeed a simpler and easier solution. Thank you.

Comment: Performing the division step earlier, e.g. $$\frac{1+\tan^2 x}{1 + \tan x} = -1 + \tan x + \frac{2}{1 + \tan x}$$ simplifies the computation further, since now we eliminate the squaring step.  The polynomial division is still required for the remainder term, however.